# Storm's multi-lang function

Tags: apache-storm

I am new in Storm. Recently I am trying to use Storm's multi-lang functions. However I have some very naive confusions.

1. I thought the interaction of multilang of Storm should come with a storm.py, storm.js or storm.rb script in multilang/resources/ folder. But I only saw them in Storm 2.0.0 snapshot version, not found in any previous version. Did I understand right? And, /multilang/resources/storm.py is different from $STORM_HOME/bin/storm.py, is that correct?
2. I can use extends ShellBolt and ShellSpout to make all components of a topology (Spouts and Bolts) working in other languages, right?

As before I only work on hardware, so this field may be new to me. Would anyone help me on these problems? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. They're moved to separate modules, and you can just add needed multilang module as a dependency in your pom. Please refer https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/1.x-branch/examples/storm-starter/pom.xml.

bin/storm.py is used for providing various commands `storm <command>`, not about multilang support.

2. Sure. Please refer SplitSentence in https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/1.x-branch/examples/storm-starter/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/starter/WordCountTopology.java

Comment: Thanks for your answer and it helps. Would  you please help to answer another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40259243/confusion-of-storm-acker-and-guaranteed-message-processing ? It is still related to the basics of Storm that confused me a lot. Thanks.